# Why is this PowerShell script deleting svn:mergeinfo from the root directory?

Tags: svn, powershell

We have a script to delete the svn:mergeinfo property from all folders inside a Subversion working copy, but not the working copy root directory itself.  It's currently an NAnt build script invoked via a separate batch file, so I'm trying to replace it with a simpler PowerShell script.  I've had three attempts at it, ranging from the naïve to the slightly more sophisticated.  All three fail my criteria, outputting the line `property 'svn:mergeinfo' deleted from '.'.`

Checking the SVN properties of the working copy root indicates that the svn:mergeinfo property has indeed been removed from this folder which is not what I want.  Each version is designed to be run from the working copy root.

Attempt 1:

```
# I understand why this one fails, it's a poor attempt.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R $_
```

Attempt 2:

```
# This one correctly lists everything except the working copy root, but
# still removes the svn:mergeinfo property from the working copy root.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Exclude $pwd | svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R $_
```

Attempt 3:

```
# Again, this one works fine until the svn propdel is added.
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { ls -R $_ } | svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R $_
```

Any thoughts on where the flaw in my logic is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn` is an external application and you cannot use PowerShell piping technique directly with it. I am not familiar with `svn` syntax and can be wrong about the details but all your commands presumably should use `ForEach-Object` (%). That is:

```
... | %{ svn propdel svn:mergeinfo -R $_ }
```

Then `svn` should “understand” the `$_` correctly. Also, it is quite possible that you should use something like `$_.FullName` or `$_.Name` instead of `$_` (again, because `svn` is an external application and it expects a string (e.g. `$_.FullName`/`$_.Name`), not an object `$_`). NB: `$_` is often converted to strings as expected automatically but this is not always the case.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks.  Do I still need the middle term, then?  The foreach-object { ls -R %_ }?  It seems like the second attempt, which is much nicer and more concise, would work correctly with this fix.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `%_` construct. Anyway, I would recommend just to experiment a little bit on your own. Use `cmd` instead of `svn`: `... | %{ cmd /c echo $_.FullName }` etc. and see what you get. If `svn` can accept a list of parameters after `-R` then there are other solutions, too.

Comment: Typo, sorry; I meant `$_`.  Thanks for the tip.